# Eclipse IDE preference history

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes, history

Is there such a thing as preference history in the Eclipse IDE?

I was messing around with some colors, etc and liked how I originally had it, however I can't seem to find the correct theme. I thought I chose a theme from the color chooser (installed from eclipse marketplace) but apparently I didn't. So I'm wondering if there is a preference history that I can revert back to what I had from yesterday lol. Does this exist?

Answer (score 0):

No. Eclipse does not keep a history of preference setting changes.